# Old Value/Search Value on search select button in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

i make a select button for search specific data on my table.
but there is problem when i click the button, the button doesn't remain or stay from past request value that i click, or it reset back to select all

so this is my form in my blade file

```
<form action="">
                <select class="form-select" name="rumah_id" id="rumah_id">
                    <option value="">Select All</option>
                    
                    @foreach($rumahs as $rumah)
                        @if(old('rumah_id') == $rumah->id)
                            <option value="{{ $rumah->id }}">{{ $rumah->alamat }}</option>
                        @else
                            <option value="{{ $rumah->id }}">{{ $rumah->alamat }}</option>
                        @endif

                    @endforeach
                </select>
</form>
```

this is my Controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $rumah = Rumah::all();
        $mobil = Mobil::with(['rumah'])->orderBy('rumah_id', 'asc')
        ->when($request->rumah_id != null, function($q) use($request){
            return $q->where('rumah_id', 'like', '%'. $request->rumah_id. '%');
        })
       return view('mobil/index',[
            'mobils' => $mobil,
            'rumahs' => $rumah,
        ]);
    }
```

also this is my migration database for rumah look like

```
Schema::create('rumahs', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id();
 $table->string('alamat');
 $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
 $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
            <select class="form-select" name="rumah_id" id="rumah_id">
                <option value="">Select All</option>
                @foreach($rumahs as $rumah)
                    <option value="{{ $rumah->id }}" {{ old('rumah_id') == $rumah->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $rumah->alamat }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

Comment: actually i found the answer, i use request instead old after value element like this and worked
<select class="form-select" name="rumah_id" id="rumah_id">
                        <option value="">Select All</option>
                        @foreach($rumahs as $rumah)
                            <option value="{{ $rumah->id }}" {{ Request::get('rumah_id') == $rumah->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $rumah->alamat }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>